# Cropping Image after caputrue or picked up from gallery

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to android just making a dummy app in which I have a dialog box which gives the option to click the image or pick an image from the gallery.
Everything is working perfectly fine I'm capturing an image from the camera then I'm saving that in my local folder in my app same as in when I pick an image from the gallery I make its copy and save in my own folder.
But I need to add 1 functionality that whenever I select image whether its from camera or gallery I should get a crop option so that when I m done with cropping that image should be saved I tried a lot but failed in giving u my code please have a look at it and if possible please give a brief answer.
thanks in advance...

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        mDob = findViewById(R.id.dob);
        mGender = findViewById(R.id.ep_gender);
        Button cancel = findViewById(R.id.ep_cancel);
        Button done = findViewById(R.id.ep_done);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.ep_username);
        TextView cPassword = findViewById(R.id.ep_password);
        backgroundPic = findViewById(R.id.iv_blur_background);
        mainProfilePic = findViewById(R.id.ep_profile_image);
        ImageView uploadPic = findViewById(R.id.iv_upload_pic);
        homeLayout = findViewById(R.id.homelayout);


        //for camera image pic
        // Checking availability of the camera
        if (!CameraUtils.isDeviceSupportCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device doesn't have camera
            finish();
        }


        //Initializing Shared Preference
        mySharedPreference = MySharedPreference.getInstance(this);

        //Initializing myDao
        AppDatabase appDatabase;
        appDatabase=AppDatabase.getInstance(this);
        myDao=appDatabase.myDao();

        fetchId();
        new MyAsyncSetData().execute();

        mGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId==R.id.ep_female){
                    gender=FEMALE;
                }else{
                    if(checkedId==R.id.ep_male){
                        gender=MALE;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mDob.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        done.setOnClickListener(this);
        cPassword.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadPic.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.dob:
                SelectDate();
                break;

            case R.id.ep_cancel:
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.ep_password:
                Intent i = new Intent(this,ChangePassword.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.ep_done:
                new MyAsyncUpdateData().execute();
                break;

            case R.id.iv_upload_pic:
                // to make background bit dully
                homeLayout.setAlpha(0.5f);

                dialog=new Dialog(this);
                Button btnGallery,btnCamera,btnRemove;

                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // used to remove the title of dialog
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialoglayout);

                btnGallery=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGalleryPicture);
                btnCamera=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
                btnRemove=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
                //dialog does not close on clicking outside

                btnGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
                btnRemove.setOnClickListener(this);

                dialog.show();// shows the dialog
                dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

                // to cancel the blurry effect on background layout
                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        homeLayout.setAlpha(1.0f);
                    }
                });
                break;

            case R.id.btnGalleryPicture:

                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_GALLERY);//one can be replaced with any action code
                dialog.dismiss();//closes the custom dialog

                break;

            case R.id.btnCapturePicture:

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                    }

                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.vshop.vshop",
                                photoFile);

                        Log.d("camera uri", photoURI.toString());
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_CAMERA);
                    }
                }

                dialog.dismiss();//closes the custom dialog
                break;

            case R.id.btnRemove:
                mCurrentPhotoPath=DEFAULT_PICTURE;
                loadDefaultImages();
                break;


        }
    }


    //loading last updated pictures to edit profile
    private void loadDefaultImages()
    {
            mainProfilePic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user));
            backgroundPic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blur));
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_CAMERA:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    LoadImages();

                } else { // Result was a failure
                    Toast.makeText(this, ERROR_CAPTURING, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;

            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO_GALLERY:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    File file=null;
                    try {
                        file=createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(file!=null)
                    {
                        boolean isCopied=copyUriToFile(this,file,selectedImage);

                        if(isCopied)
                        {
                            LoadImages();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void LoadImages(){

        //using Universal Image Loader Library for loading and displaying image
        ImageLoader.getInstance()
                .displayImage(mCurrentPhotoPath//string url
                        ,mainProfilePic);//imageview for showing image

         Uri myUri = Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), myUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BlurImage.with(getApplicationContext()).load(bitmap).intensity(10).Async(true).into(backgroundPic);

      /*  ImageLoader.getInstance()
                .displayImage(mCurrentPhotoPath//string url
                        ,backgroundPic);*/
    }


    public class MyAsyncSetData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,User>{

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            User user = SetOldResult(user_id);
            return user;
        }

        //Initializing Query to get details of current user
        private User SetOldResult(long id){
            User user;
            user = myDao.getUserDetails(id);
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User user) {

            String gender = user.getGender();
            String dob = user.getDob();
            String fName = user.getFname();
            String lName = user.getLname();
            String Name = fName + " " + lName;
            String picUri =user.getImageUri();
            userName.setText(Name);
            mDob.setText(dob);

            if(gender.equals("male")){
                mGender.check(R.id.ep_male);
            }
            else if(gender.equals("female")){
                mGender.check(R.id.ep_female);
            }

            if (picUri.equals(DEFAULT_PICTURE)){
                backgroundPic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blur));
                mainProfilePic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user));
            }else {

                mCurrentPhotoPath=picUri;
                LoadImages();

            }
        }
    }



        public class MyAsyncUpdateData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mProgressDialog=new ProgressDialog(EditProfile.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Updating");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Your current changes are being updated please wait..");
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            //just to show dialog box to delay our action by 3 seconds
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            int i = myDao.updateGenderAndDob(mCurrentPhotoPath,gender,mDob.getText().toString(),user_id);
            return i;
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if(integer>0){
                    mySharedPreference.savePathProfileImage(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    finish();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,ERROR_UPDATING,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }


        //Getting Id of current logged in user
        private void fetchId(){
            user_id = mySharedPreference.fetchId();
        }

        // method to pick and set dob
        private void SelectDate(){

            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();//to get current time and date

            int currentYear= calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int currentMonth=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int currentDay=calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mDob.setText(dayOfMonth+"."+(month+1)+"."+year);
                }
            },currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.setCancelable(false);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }

        //used to create new file in our own app folder
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName, /* prefix */
                    ".jpg", /* suffix */
                    storageDir /* directory */
            );

            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file://"+image.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("camera", mCurrentPhotoPath);
            return image;
        }


        //This is used to copy image_file from gallery to local app folder
        public boolean copyUriToFile(Context c, File file, Uri uri) {
            try {
                InputStream is = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                copyStream(is, fos);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
                throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you have problems with? if it crashes, whats the stacktrace then?

Comment: No problem at all its working perfectly fine i just want to add a feature of cropping an image whenever i select from gallery or camera like in whatsapp when we upload a new pic as our dp there comes an cropper through which we crop the images and that portion is only set